# Tkinter - get text from Scrolledtext box (with grid management) and save into sqlite3 tabel - python 3.5 - windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

can you please help me?

What i am trying to do:

I am trying to create a form where user put data and when click on a button it will save all the data into a sqlite 3 table

(The original program is longer, it has many other entry boxes, so i just create a smaller one with the code that get me the error message)

The problem:
when i click on the button, the system generate this error message (probabily something is wrong with my scrolledtext)

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\sheha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "scrolledtext_test.py", line 36, in add_entry_command
>       backend.insert(sb1.get(), sb2.get()) TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Thank you in advance

Please find the code here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import backend
import csv
from backend import write_to_csv
import os
from Send_email_gui import send_email
from backend import check_assignment
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import tkinter.ttk
import sqlite3

"""
functions for sqllite table creation and insert
"""

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("test.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scrolltext (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sb1_ text, sb2_ text)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(sb1_, sb2_):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("test.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO scrolltext VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)", (sb1_, sb2_))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

"""
function for tkinter button
"""
def add_entry_command():
    backend.insert(sb1.get(), sb2.get())


def __init__(self, sb1_, sb2_):
        self.sb1_=sb1_
        self.sb2_=sb2_



root=Tk()
root.title("How to get text from scrolledtex and save into sqlite3")
root.geometry("1366x768")


l22=Label(root, text="BKG Suggestions", wraplength=250)
l22.grid(row=27, column=2, sticky='E')

l23=Label(root, text="YE Suggestions", wraplength=250)
l23.grid(row=27, column=6, sticky='NS')

"""
Entry boxes top
"""

sb1=ScrolledText(root, height=4, width=25)
sb1.grid(row=27, column=4)

sb2=ScrolledText(root, height=4, width=25)
sb2.grid(row=27, column=7)

"""
Button
"""

b1=Button(root, text="Submit to sqlite3", width=12, command=add_entry_command)
b1.grid(row=34, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that 
there are many similarities between `scrollText` and `tkinter.Text`.

In `tkinter.Text`,you should use `.get(1.0,"end")` if you want to get the text in it.
It is the same in `scrollText`.So the `add_entry_command` function should be:

```
def add_entry_command():
    # After Mr.Bryan's suggestion.
    backend.insert(sb1.get("1.0","end-1c"), sb2.get("1.0","end-1c"))
```

Comment: Most often, `"end-1c"` is the proper second index. Otherwise, you end up getting the extra newline that is automatically added by the text widget.  Also, the first index should be `"1.0"`, not `1.0`. Indexes are strings, not floating-point numbers. `1.0` works, but it's technically poor style and incorrect.